# format array of object using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and I'm trying to format the object array it returns when using find(). I tried to use the map but I believe it is not the best option

**original format**

```
[
  {
    "unity": "hectares",
    "_id": "5f4c254ade37fc133cdedc1e",
    "name": "Talhão ABC-1020",
    "size": 164,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-30T22:16:42.080Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "unity": "hectares",
    "_id": "4g4c254ade37fc133cdedc8e",
    "name": "Talhão ABC-1021",
    "size": 164,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-30T22:32:51.824Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

**how i want it to be**

```
[
  {
    "field_id": "5f4c254ade37fc133cdedc1e",
    "name": "Talhão ABC-1020",
    "size": 164,
    "unity": "hectares",
  },
  {
    "field_id": "4g4c254ade37fc133cdedc8e",
    "name": "Talhão ABC-1021",
    "size": 164,
    "unity": "hectares",
  },
]
```

**code**

```
async index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const field = await Field.find({})    
      return res.status(200).json(field)
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ err });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using `map()` is best option. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I tried but it greatly increases the response time. How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mongoose's [Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) function to return plain Javascript objects. You then can modify these returned objects.

Something likes

```
async index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const fields = await Field.find({}).lean();    
      const formattedFields = fields.map((field) => ({field_id, name, size, unity} = field, {field_id, name, size, unity}));
      return res.status(200).json(formattedFields)
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ err });
    }
  }
```